# how to do set() function in Python 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I created a 2D array  with n elements!

```
n = int(input())
a = [[input(),float(input())] for _ in range(n)]
```

output

```
a = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ......... ['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0],['Marsh', 35.5]]
```

how to find 2nd lowest score & corresponding names using sort() & set() in python,without using multiple loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
a = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.21], ['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0],['Marsh', 35.5]]
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
print(a)

print('second lowest is :' )
print(a[1])

# these lines add on second edit
import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
a[[i for i in (range(len(list(a)))) if a[i][1] == a[1][1]],:]
```

output:

```
[['Marsh', 35.5], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39.0], ['Akriti', 41.0]]
second lowest is :
['Harry', 37.21]
array([['Harry', '37.21'],
       ['Berry', '37.21'],
       ['Tina', '37.21']], dtype='<U6')
```

if you want to use `set()` you can try this:

```
a = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.21], ['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0],['Marsh', 35.5]]
b = set(tuple(t) for t in a)
b = sorted(b, key=lambda x: x[1])
b
```

output:

```
[('Marsh', 35.5),
 ('Berry', 37.21),
 ('Harry', 37.21),
 ('Tina', 37.21),
 ('Harsh', 39.0),
 ('Akriti', 41.0)]
```

Comment: @RENJITHV.S, thanks, no problem, if you input `a` to my code you can find 2nd lowest person

Comment: if i have multiple min() value what to do?

Comment: @RENJITHV.S, I edit code block one for your request if having multiple min()